# QListView whitespace

Tags: qt, qlistview, qabstractitemview

I have a `QListView` with some items in it. I would like to know the bounding box of the content that is presented. Here is an illustration:

[image: Illustration]

As you can see, the geometry of the ListView (whole black area) does not match the geometry of the contents. There is quite some unused whitespace (or lets say, black space).

I would like to know the geometry minus that whitespace. I denoted that in the illustration with transparent yellow stripes. That's the region I would like to know.

Is there a way to get that out of the `QListView` or even `QAbstractItemView`?

Comment: you've already tried `contentsRect()` I presume?

Comment: That would be too easy! Yes I tried it just to make sure.

Comment: what's the size policy? Is it in a dock widget (because sizing dock widgets properly is a *whole* other ballgame)?

Comment: yeah it is, but I don't really have a sizing problem, I just need to know the offset of the "real" content to the bottom